# How to make last list item different to others in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and an adapter:

```
public class PaymentMethodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PaymentMethodAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<PaymentMethod> mPaymentMethods = new ArrayList<>(0);

    public PaymentMethodAdapter(List<PaymentMethod> paymentMethods) {
        mPaymentMethods = paymentMethods;
        int size = mPaymentMethods.size();
        mPaymentMethods.add(size + 1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_payment_method_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (mPaymentMethods.get(position) == null) {  // Last item
            // Display add payment method item.

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPaymentMethods.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.item_payment_method_image_view) ImageView paymentImageView;
        @Bind(R.id.item_payment_method_card_number_text_view) TextView cardNumberTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.item_current_payment_method_image_view) ImageView currentMethodImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make it so that when the last element in `mPaymentMethods` is reached a different list item layout is used. Basically I want to customize the last item in the list.

How do I customize the last item in a list use a different layout to the other items in the same list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should override getItemViewType accordingly as follows.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == mPaymentMethods.size() - 1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Initiate viewholder according to the view type

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view;
   if(viewType == 0){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_payment_method_list_0, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder0(view);
   } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_payment_method_list_1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder1(view);
   }

}
```

finally use the chosen layout

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   if (holder instanceOf ViewHolder0){
      //do stuff with layout 0
   } else {
      // do stuff with layout 1
   }        
 }
```

Comment: So the ViewHolder0 and ViewHolder1 classes should extend the ViewHolder class. Does that mean I need 3 view holder classes? @Uğur B

Comment: No you need 2 classes for 2 layout. first u can use ViewHolder class for first viewtype that you implemented and you need another class (call it as you wish) and initiate view items of the layout which you inflated for second viewtype.